# How does developers make to hide informations in Android Apps?

Tags: encryption, android-sqlite, password-encryption

Well, I would like to understand how I can hide precious data in my android app like passwords, so I have seen in rooted devices the users can find databases and SharedPreferences of the app. If I need to save any precious data in running time, how could I do it?

Comment: Don't store that info on a device. Use a server, instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can hash user password and then save it, when you want to verify entered password with primary password, you have to hash entered password and then compare it with primary hashed password. because when you hash a string, you can't retrieve it to first string. to hash a string use SHA1 or MD5 hashing Technics.
see
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-28-implement-sha1-and-md5-hashing-in-android/